Can the inequality $X \preceq \sqrt{A} (\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{A}$ be written more simply?
Let $A, B, X$ be three real, symmetric positive semidefinite matrices and suppose that the inequality
$$
X \preceq \sqrt{A} (\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{A}
$$
holds where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ denotes the positive semidefinite square-root of a matrix.
In the case that $A, B $ are both nonsingular, we can write this inequality equivalently as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} X & X \\ X & X \end{pmatrix} \preceq 
\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 &  B^{-1}\end{pmatrix}. \qquad \mbox{$(*)$}
$$
(See proof below.)
Question: Is there an analogous "simpler" form when $A, B$ are possibly singular (i.e., positive semidefinite but not necessarily definite)?

Proof of $(*)$:
Set $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A^{-1} & I \\ B & - I \end{smallmatrix}\right)$; note that it is nonsingular. Hence the inequality above is equivalent to
$$
0 \succeq M^T \begin{pmatrix} X - A & X \\ X & X - B^{-1} \end{pmatrix} M = \begin{pmatrix}  A^{-1}XA^{-1} + BXB + A^{-1}XB + BXA^{-1} - (B + A^{-1})& 0 \\ 0&  -(A + B^{-1}) \end{pmatrix}
$$
Or equivalently,
$$
(B+A^{-1})X (B+A^{-1}) \preceq  (B + A^{-1})
$$
Which is in turn equivalent to
$$
X \preceq (B + A^{-1})^{-1} = \sqrt{A} (\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} + I)^{-1}\sqrt{A}. \hspace{5mm}\square 
$$

If you allow $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{B}$ in your desired expression, it is possible using Schur complement.

How do you do that?

No, sorry, got the sign mixed up in my head.

Ah, yes, the lower bound $\succeq$ version is essentially a Schur complement. Unfortunately, it is the other direction that I need.

I am using the formula for the inverse here (Inverse of $I+BA$ is $(I+BA)^{-1} = I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A$)
$$
  (I+CD)^{-1} = I - C(I+DC)^{-1}D \ .
$$
We then have the series of equivalence
\begin{align*}
  X \preceq \sqrt{A} (I + \sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} ) ^{-1} \sqrt{A} \\
  X \preceq \sqrt{A} [I - \sqrt{A}B (I+\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}B)^{-1} \sqrt{A}] \sqrt{A} & \quad \text{using $C=\sqrt{A}B$ and $D=\sqrt{A}$} \\
  X \preceq A(I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A) \\
  X \preceq A(I+BA)^{-1} & \quad \text{using $C=B$ and $D=A$} \\
  (I+BA)^{T}X(I+BA) \preceq A+A^TBA \\
  \begin{pmatrix} I \\ A \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} X-A & XB \\ B^TX & B^TXB-B \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I \\ A \end{pmatrix} \preceq 0 \\
\end{align*}
